# PostgreSQL access to generate_series() cells

Tags: postgresql, join, generate-series

I'm generating a date series via PostgreSQL's `generate_series(min, max)` in the following way:

```
SELECT 
    generate_series(getstartdate(some arguments)
                  , getenddate(some arguments), interval '1 day')
FROM taskresults
```

`getstartdate()` and `getenddate()` are each returning the start- and end date of a given task. I have more tables `Employees(employeeid, taskid, worktime)` and `Tasks(taskid, startdate, enddate)`.

My goal is to get the employees working time grouped by each day from my generated series. How can I perform this join? Note that I do not have direct access to the columns `startdate` and `enddate` in the table `Tasks` I can only access the dates via those functions mentioned above. The worktime is in hours/day so I have to aggregate it via `SUM()` for each task the employee works in to the given date in the series. The problem is that I don't how to access a date in the generated series.

**EDIT**
Data structures:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  employeeid serial NOT NULL,
  firstname character varying(32),
  lastname character varying(32),
  qualification character varying(32),
  incomeperhour numeric,
)
CREATE TABLE employeetasks
(
  projectid integer,
  taskid integer,
  employeeid integer,
  hoursperday real,
)
CREATE TABLE taskresults
(
  simulationid integer,
  taskid integer,
  duration integer
)
CREATE TABLE tasks
(
  projectid integer NOT NULL,
  taskname character varying(32),
  startdate character varying(32),
  enddate character varying(32),
  predecessor integer,
  minduration integer,
  maxduration integer,
  taskid integer,
)
```

Some explanation:
The whole database is for simulation so at first you define a task schedule (in table `tasks`) and then run the simulation that inserts the results into `taskresults`. As you can see I only store the `duration` in the results that's why I can only access the date ranges for each task with the `getstartdate` / `getenddate` functions. The table `employeetasks` basically assigns employees from the `employees` table to the `task` table with an hour-amount they're working in that task per day.

Comment: What's the definition of "taskresults"?

Comment: I updated my post with table definitions and some explanations

Comment: I just can't work out how the rest is supposed to fit together, what exactly the issue you're having is, or what these magic getstartdate and getenddate functions are meant to do.

Comment: The task table stores the tasks and they can be defined in 4 different types (startdate + minmax duration, enddate + minmaxduration, startdate + enddate, predecessor + minmaxduration). The 3rd type is the only type where I can get the fixed start and end date. In the other 3 cases the rest of columns defining the tasks date range are NULL. getstartdate/getenddate basically returns me the dates by building avgs/quantiles via the duration in taskresults. I hope that's somehow understandable :/

Comment: I think you need to simplify your schema down to the minimum to illustrate the problem you need help with, getting rid of all the extraneous and irrelevant complexity.

Comment: Vague guess is something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7aab5/5 but with no sample data, missing functions, etc it's kinda hard to do much.

Comment: And my issue is that I can't join the generated date series with the employees working time amount when they're working parallely in an arbitrary amount of different tasks

Comment: Sounds like you need a common table expression (`WITH`) or to use `FROM (SELECT ...)`, using `generate_series` in the `SELECT`-list, then filter and aggregate it in the outer query. See my SQLFiddle.

Comment: Ok thanks for help and trying to understand my issue I'll check it out

Comment: Come to think of it, you're doing it the hard way. Just `generate_series` from min(startdate) to max(enddate) across all values of interest, CROSS JOIN on it, then use `workday BETWEEN getstartdate(...) AND getenddate(...)` to filter out ones that're outside the reasonable range.

Comment: Shouldn't I avoid using functions in WHERE-clauses? Despite the fact that my db schema is kind of messed up

Comment: If they're slow functions it wouldn't be ideal to use them in the WHERE clause, no. You're going to need to do some multi-level CTEs or nested `FROM (SELECT ...)`s.

Comment: No worries. If you don't have any luck after working on it a while, post a new question with an SQLFiddle that shows a simplified schema with sample data, and post a hand-created "expected results" table.

Comment: Hey I'm almost there where I want to be. I got it down do this table result: http://666kb.com/i/c81fvknm1p2odffjm.gif I just have to "merge" it with the generated date series. Can you give me any advice on that? Cheers

Comment: Ok got it the query is kind of nasty but has quite good performance your advices helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `JOIN` on the generated series like anything else.

```
INNER JOIN generate_series(getstartdate(some arguments), getenddate(some arguments), interval '1 day') workday ON (...)
```

The join condition is hard to work out without knowing how your data is stored.

Also, your data structure is weird. Employees have a "taskid"? n:1 employees -> task? I can't really write a full query 'cos I don't get the data structure.